# Oracle use PIPELINE FUNCTION TO SELECT FROM Objects Types

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I would like to create an Oracle package accessing an Oracle object of table type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_dept_avg_rec AS OBJECT( 
  dept  number, 
  age   number
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_dept_avg_tab IS TABLE OF t_dept_avg_rec
```

Insert few records into the above object type table as mentioned below.

```
  dept, age
  ----- ---
 - 20,   60
 - 30,   40
 - 20,   24
 - 30,   66
```

Then create a separate oracle pipelined function to return the following result.

```
select dept, avg(age)
  from t_dept_avg_tab
group by dept;
```

Is this possible using Oracle objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t_dept_avg_tab` is a SQL type so you can use it directly in a FROM with a TABLE() function:

```
SQL> select dept, avg(age)
  2  from table(t_dept_avg_tab(t_dept_avg_rec(20,60)
  3                         , t_dept_avg_rec(30,40)
  4                         , t_dept_avg_rec(20,24)
  5                         , t_dept_avg_rec(30,66)))
  6  group by dept
  7  /

      DEPT   AVG(AGE)
---------- ----------
        30         53
        20         42

SQL>
```